# How to compare multiple strings?

Tags: java

I was wondering how I can compare multiple strings in one line. I tried using the || but it doesn't work for booleans or strings. this is what my code is like:

```
}else if(question != "a" || "b") {
    System.out.println("Sorry that isn't an A or a B");
```

For those who marked it duplicate, I checked over 200 questions here on stack overflow, and none worked. The one @Chrylis posted actually didn't help. they were just asking about the difference in == and .equals()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, don't use `==` for strings. You'll learn why later. You want to compare strings by their contents, not where they are in memory. In rare cases a string of `"a"` could compare false to another string called `"a"`.

Second, split it up so you are performing boolean logic on the comparison results:

```
else if(!(question.equals("a") || question.equals("b")) {
```

Comment: Presumably the OP is asking about an approach that would scale well as the number of strings is increased.

Comment: @arshajii If that's an assumption you wish to make, go ahead. I'm going to leave this with my own assumptions and interpretation however.

Comment: hexafraction, I was hoping this would work, and while it exempted me form errors, but when I put an input of c, it doesnt run the code v.v

Comment: also, I usually don't use ==. I just was not sure how else to do it except for !=
I am fairly new to Java (while ive been coding for awhile, but i never really went in depth(im still only 13))
i wasnt sure if you could do an if(!(ques..."b")) {

Comment: @hexafraction if i was to upload a picture, could you figure it out possibly? I have not the slightest clue why it wont run correctly

Comment: The cases where two strings `"a"` aren't `==` aren't even rare. It's probably more rare that they _are_ `==`.

Comment: @yshavit if i have my code running, but it doesnt continue after accepting the unknown variable (it wont run the code) how can i fix it?

Comment: `}else if(!(question.equals("a") || question.equals("b"))) {
    System.out.println("Sorry that isn't an A or a B");
     try {
         Thread.sleep(2000);
     } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
         Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
     }`

Comment: What code won't it run? What's the value of `question`?

Comment: @ yshavitthe value of question was c, and it wouldnt run the System.out.println("Sorry that isn't an A or a B");

Answer (score 5):

You can try using [`Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29):

```
else if (!Arrays.asList("a", "b").contains(question)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Isn't that a bit overkill?

Comment: @hexafraction This seems to be the whole point of the question; an approach that works for an arbitrary number of strings.

Comment: Correct logic, but not a good way to code it. (`ImmutableSet` would be great, though.)

Comment: @chrylis No I disagree: this has very little overhead. Much less than an `ImmutableSet` or something of the kind.

Comment: Is `Arrays.asList()` considered a compile-time constant? (`ImmutableSet` is just a wrapper around a fixed-size array anyway.)

Comment: @chrylis No, the JLS does not consider it such.

Comment: @chrylis What class are you talking about anyway? Guava's `ImmutableSet`?

Comment: @arshajii Yes, Guava's. These days Guava is on the list of near-reflexive dependencies, like slf4j and commons-lang.

Answer (score 1):

Two things wrong: You can't just specify multiple values with `||` (or `&&`) like that.  You need to specify both the left side and the right side explicitly each time.

Second, use [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) to compare `String` values, not the `==` (or in this case `!=`) operators.  `==` compares two object references to see if they are the same object.

```
} else if (!("a".equals(question) || "b".equals(question)))
```

Or an alternative is to [make a temporary `List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) and use [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29), which might be clearer for longer lists of things to test:

```
} else if (!Arrays.asList("a", "b").contains(question))
```

Comment: Or make your own helper function: `boolean isOneOf(String s, String ... a) { for (String as : a) if (as.equals(s)) return true; return false; }`

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] options = {"a", "b"}; // Must be sorted.
if (java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(options, question) < 0) {
  System.out.println("Sorry that isn't an A or a B");
}
```

Alternatively (assuming your strings don't contain `|`:

```
if ("a|b".indexOf(question) == -1) {
  System.out.println("Sorry that isn't an A or a B");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, you should use `equals` for objects not `==`

To answer your question, you have to repeat the equals call on both sides of the `||`

```
}else if( ! (question.equals("a") || question.equals("b"))  ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
}else if( !(question.equals("a") || question.equals("b")) {
    System.out.println("Sorry that isn't an A or a B");
```

You can't do `NOT equals a OR b`

You have to do `NOT(equals a OR equals b)`

Secondly, you are comparing strings with `!=`, but you should be comparing strings using the .`equals(String)` method. This has been said millions of times, but: `==` and `!=` are comparing object *references*, whereas `.equals(String)` is comparing String *values*.